# How to left join on two tables that need filtering?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have two tables that need to be joined together, but both tables need to be filtered first. Right now I have two tables open in SQL Server, and both are select*'d on specific columns to only give specific results. Basically, if this was Excel, I would filter both spreadsheets and then `VLOOKUP`.

I am afraid that my left join will give me the results of table 2 with ALL rows (50,000), vs the 15,000 rows I actually have to use.

- Table 1 - Supplier Name (3,000 records)
- Table 2 - Supplier Name (15,000 records)

I just need to join the tables so I can see how many 1:1 matches come back to table 1. We are just looking for a 100% 1:1 match.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Rule of thumb: *rows from the inner table are filtered in ON and rows from the outer table in WHERE*. Or you put both Selects in CTEs and join them.

Comment: So I could just create a query and do this?

Select* table 1 --
Select* table 2 --

Join --

If I run that entire list of code, will that ensure that my join is done on the two tables AFTER they have been filtered for desired results?

Comment: Probably, show your existing queries.

Comment: Could you help me create the left join? I have never left joined one column to one column, so I think I'm overthinking it. I basically need to replicate a vlookup on table 1 using table 2 as the lookup value.

Comment: @NicholasGabriele If you want a 1:1 match, you do not want a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I already know that there will be 2,995 1:1 matches and 5 NULLS. I did the test in Excel, but now need to replicate in SQL. I believe that a LEFT JOIN should give me all 3,000 with their name match or NULL, right?

Comment: If you know there are 3000 rows in Table1 and want to return 100% of them regardless if a match exists in Table2, then yes, you will want to do a LEFT JOIN to Table2. That is **not** a 100% 1:1 match you mention in your original question. Both of my examples below can have their `INNER JOIN` changed to `LEFT JOIN` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know you want all the records from Table1 first, then you can add your filtering conditions to the JOIN's ON statement for table2, or JOIN on a derived table2.

INNER JOIN filter example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2
    ON t1.SupplierId = t2.SupplierId
    AND t2.Column1 = ...condition
    AND t2.Column2 = ...condition
WHERE
   ...Table1 filters
```

INNER JOIN on a derived table:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ...Table2 filters
) AS t2
    ON t1.SupplierId = t2.SupplierId
WHERE
   ...Table1 filters
```

To return all rows from Table1 regardless if a match exists in Table2, then you can perform a LEFT JOIN instead.

LEFT JOIN filter example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2
    ON t1.SupplierId = t2.SupplierId
    AND t2.Column1 = ...condition
    AND t2.Column2 = ...condition
WHERE
   ...Table1 filters
```

LEFT JOIN on a derived table:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ...Table2 filters
) AS t2
    ON t1.SupplierId = t2.SupplierId
WHERE
   ...Table1 filters
```

**UPDATE:**

*I just want a column in table 1 showing essentially a match or a NULL.*

```
/*
    Show all rows in [2020_supplier1] where SetID = 'ID' 
    and a count of matching records from [2020supplier2]
*/

SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.[Supplier Name],
    n.Table2Count -- will be NULL without a match.
FROM [2020_supplier1] AS t1 
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT COUNT ( * ) AS Table2Count FROM [2020supplier2] AS t2
    WHERE
        t2.[Vendor Name] = t1.[Supplier Name]
        AND t2.[Engagement Status] = 'your condition'
        -- any additional filters...

) AS n
WHERE 
    t1.[SetID] = 'ID';
```

You can simplify this even further and save processing time if you don't care about a [2020supplier2] count with the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.[Supplier Name],
    n.VendorMatch
FROM [2020_supplier1] AS t1 
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (

            SELECT * FROM [2020supplier2] AS t2 WHERE
                t2.[Vendor Name] = t1.[Supplier Name]
                AND t2.[Engagement Status] = 'your condition'
                -- any additional filters...
        
        ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS VendorMatch

) AS n
WHERE 
    t1.[SetID] = 'ID';
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a left join? I want all 1:1 matches as well as all results from table 1 (3,000 rows) that have NO match to table 2, i.e. NULL, N/A.

That is the most important part, as I am interested in calling out any suppliers that are in table 1 but NOT in table 2.

Comment: I think we have two very different ideas of what a 1:1 match means in the relational database world. If you want ALL rows from Table1 regardless of Table2's matches, then yes, replace the `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @NicholasGabriele I have updated my Answer to include the `LEFT JOIN` examples.

Comment: For some reason, this is giving me 5,000+ results. My first table is only 3,000 rows, so I'm not sure why the join is giving back more data than requested. My code is -

``` Select*  FROM .[2020_supplier1] as t1
LEFT JOIN .[2020supplier2] as t2
 ON t1.[Supplier Name] = t2.[Vendor Name]

WHERE t1.[SetID] = 'ID' AND t2.[Engagement Status] = ' ```

Comment: @NicholasGabriele  The condition on `t2.[Engagement Status]` should be moved to the ON. But it seems like you got multiple matching rows (1-to-many) and you just want one of them. Then you need some logic to define *which* row to be returned/joined

Comment: @NicholasGabriele What are the results if your run `SELECT * FROM [2020_supplier1] AS t1 WHERE t1.[SetID] = 'ID';`? Also, try modifying your statement to `SELECT * FROM [2020_supplier1] AS t1 LEFT JOIN [2020supplier2] AS t2 ON t1.[Supplier Name] = t2.[Vendor Name]  AND t2.[Engagement Status] = 'your condition' WHERE  t1.[SetID] = 'ID';`

Comment: I see. It looks like SQL needs strict definitions for every piece of the code. My 2nd table has 16,000 results and many duplicates, however, it doesn't matter which supplier name comes back out of x duplicates, I just need to verify that it's at least there. VLOOKUP can easily do this.. for a 3,000 result table, I lookup vs the 16,000 table and receive only 3,000 results with either 1) the supplier name or 2) #N/A

Comment: @NicholasGabriele Are you simply trying to view suppliers in Table1 who have records in Table2? Do you not care to display the data in Table2?

Comment: Yes, I just want a column in table 1 showing essentially a match or a NULL. This will then give me my % of total suppliers that are validated in both systems.

The tricky part is that both tables need to be slightly filtered before joining. Table 1 needs to be filtered for "ID", which brings it to 3,000 rows, and table 2 needs to be filtered for active suppliers (or blank, hence "") which brings it to 16,000 rows.

Comment: @NicholasGabriele Check out the UPDATE to my answer.

Comment: @CriticalError that worked! Thanks so much. I wish it was as simple as what I was able to do in excel, but hopefully one day I can get to the point where it is as simple. Thanks again.

Sorry, one more question (but your solution was checked as answered). Is there a way to take these 3,026 rows and remove duplicates based on supplier name? I can do it in Excel, but that doesn't force me to learn it in SQL.

Comment: @NicholasGabriele I updated my update to select distinct supplier names.

Comment: Actually, now that I'm going through the data I don't know if this is correct. It looks like SQL gave me the correct row count I had in excel (3,000 matches), but there is no column showing the name pulled from table 2. The count column shows duplicates, but it also has a lot of "0"s which tells me there is no 1:1 match? After some spot checking it seems that it's false.

I tried running the second code to save processing power and I am getting incorrect syntax near my t2.[engagement status] = '' and line 39, 'AS'.

Comment: @NicholasGabriele Message me your full SQL.

Comment: I was able to tweak it and add some filters in to reach the desired result. Thank you again, I really appreciate it man.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about data from the 2nd table you can use this approach:

```
with cte as 
 ( -- return unique [Vendor Name] only
   select distinct [Vendor Name]
   from [2020supplier2]
   where [Engagement Status] = 'whatever'
 )
Select t1.*
   -- if there's no matching row the Outer Join returns NULL
   ,case when t2.[Vendor Name] is null then 0 else 1 end as suppplier_exists
FROM [2020_supplier1] as t1
LEFT JOIN cte as t2
  ON t1.[Supplier Name] = t2.[Vendor Name]
WHERE t1.[SetID] = 'ID'
```

Comment: this looks good, but do you know how to add multiple filters to "where [Engagement Status] = ' whatever'?

I would like to add 'blank' and 'open'. I tried and but it errored out

Comment: `where [Engagement Status] in  ('blank', 'open', 'whatever')`?